# Show entries that I have in common with an user, seperated by likes and dislikes

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a page system like the one on facebook where every user can like or even dislike a page. `status = 1` is a like, `0` is a dislike.

This is my query:

```
SELECT  
p.title_de, de, p.keyname, l.status,
(CASE WHEN l.status = '1' THEN title_de END) AS liked,
(CASE WHEN l.status = '0' THEN title_de END) AS disliked
FROM pages_likes l  
JOIN pages p on p.id = l.page_id 
WHERE  p.keyname != 'rship'  AND l.uid = '311'  
GROUP BY l.page_id  
ORDER BY p.title_de ASC
```

Questions:

1) I also want to count all liked and disliked entries by that user. At the moment I wrote an extra query for that but I wonder if it would be more efficient to implement that count in that query already? I tried to use `COUNT` but then I only get one result back from the whole query.

2) I want to display common/mutual likes I have with this user (`uid` means user_id). I tried to add an `AND 'uid' = 1` to `WHERE` but that didn't work. This should also be seperated by likes and dislikes (`status = 1` and `0`). I suppose I should write a subquery with `UNION`? But I don't know how exactly.

This is my structure:

[image]

Comment: You have no aggregating functions. So, why do you have GROUP BY clause? And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: To avoid duplicate page entries I output as page title.

Comment: `sum(l.status) as liked, count(l.status)-sum(l.status) as disliked`

Comment: What should accomplish that? I primarily want to count mutual likes/dislikes I have with a specific user.

Comment: What is `title_de`?

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change those cases to

```
SUM(l.status = 1) AS likes,
SUM(l.status = 0) AS dislikes,
```